What is the alternative way to get authenticationManagerBean() without WebSecurityConfigurer?
WebSecurityConfigurer is already deprecrated.
For now I use AbstractHttpConfigurer and META-INF/ Spring factories as Spring team recommend.
org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.AbstractHttpConfigurer = sample.MyClassThatExtendsAbstractHttpConfigurer

public class SecurityConfig extends AbstractHttpConfigurer{}

How can I get the AuthenticationManager bean here? Previously we use authenticationManagerBean(). What should we use now?
I didn't find any related Spring Doc about this part. Can you please share an example?

In what context do you want to access it? Is the ApplicationContext or still building?

Did you read https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/servlet/config.html#_publish_an_authenticationmanager_bean

Why do you even need it?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Here is how you can get bean of AuthenticationManager in latest spring security
 @Bean
 AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration configuration) throws Exception {
    return configuration.getAuthenticationManager();
 }

